# How to change version of gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to update a gem (specifically bootstrap-sass) to the latest version (3.1.1). To do this I first edited the Gemfile to change the bootstrap line to this:

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '3.1.1'
```

Then I ran

```
bundle install
bundle update
bundle install
```

and started the server, but when looking at the custom CSS file with Bootstrap included, the CSS included was still version 2.3.2. There is probably a simple answer to this question to force the update upon all components of the app, but how do I apply this update?

Here's the Github repo so people can help debug faster:
https://github.com/afuhrtrumpet/menu_app

Comment: Did you try manually editing Gemfile.lock? I know it's not recommended but it could solve your problem

Comment: I could, but Gemfile.lock already lists `bootstrap-sass (3.1.1.0)`, so I don't see a need to.

Comment: Oh sorry, my bad for not reading the question properly. Um, I've never worked with bootstrap but would a general gem update work?

Comment: I've tried that several times and it's updated the Gemfile.lock, but not the actual CSS used in the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The old version of bootstrap-sass was still installed along with the new version and was still being used. The following command fixed it:

```
gem cleanup bootstrap-sass
```

Answer (score 2):

Per the bootstrap-sass readme.md at:
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass

Make sure you have sass-rails in your Gemfile too.

gem 'sass-rails', '>= 3.2'

Since you already had been running bootstrap, I presume you have *@import 'bootstrap'* in your CSS tree.

Comment: Did you specify 'sass-rails' version 3.2 or higher?

Comment: I currently have >= 4.0.0 specified. For easier debugging, the full repo has been added to the post now.

Answer (score 0):

Delete Gemfile.lock, and rerun bundle commands

Comment: I just tried that, and still ended up with the old version of Bootstrap.

Comment: Also, I checked Gemfile.lock and it does contain bootstrap-sass 3.1.1

Comment: rake assets:precompile

Comment: I tried that and got the same results. Or maybe I'm supposed to to another `bundle update` after running this?